# Store user input String into array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

User input into array.

E.g.

```
    private void addVideo()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
    String message = "Video";
    System.out.print("Enter Video Name: ");
    return in.nextLine();
}
```

In in class:

```
    public static String nextLine()
{   
    return in.nextLine(); 
}
```

I have compile error 'incompatible types: unexpected return value.'
What is the problem? explanation will be appreciated.

Thanks!

How do I assign the entered video name into an array? e.g. first video name into id array(id=1) second is id = 2 and so on?

Comment: why the return type of method `addVideo()` is void when its returning string

Comment: method signature is `void` but returning `String`

Answer (score 2):

```
private String addVideo() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String message = "Video";
        System.out.print("Enter Video Name: ");
        return in.nextLine();
    }
```

in.nextLine() is returning a String value, so you have to use String not void

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to store the video names into an array you could just use the method outlined by Nikolai Hristov and then add each instance to an array like this

```
String[] videos = new String[10];
videos[0] = addVideo();
videos[1] = addVideo();
```

Each call to `addVideo()` will prompt the user for a video name and then return a String to that position of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a method with the return type `void` yet you used a `return` statement in the method.

As for how to do it, try something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public String addVideo() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = "Video";
    System.out.println("Enter Video Name: ");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    list.add(input);
    return input;
}
```

Each time you call addVideo you will add one video to the list.